# How to recover Chrome bookmarks in windows 8

Tags: windows, google-chrome, bookmarks

I lost my Bookmarks when i accidentally synced another Google account in my Chrome. Is there a way for me to recover my bookmarks?

I've already tried to re-sync, but the bookmarks were replaced.

Please help!

I have windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

If your bookmarks are synced, then login with your google account and open this link: https://www.google.com/bookmarks/, else it's more complicated.

Comment: I guess they're not :(